# When the piecewise constant integral independs of the partition's choice?

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-integration, partitions-for-integration

**Proposition**

Let $I$ be a bounded interval, and let $f:I\to\textbf{R}$ be a function. Suppose that $\textbf{P}$ and $\textbf{P}'$ are partitions of $I$ such that $f$ is piecewise constant both with respect to $\textbf{P}$ and with respect to $\textbf{P}'$. Then
\begin{align*}
p.c.\int_{[\textbf{P}]}f = p.c.\int_{[\textbf{P}']}f
\end{align*}

**My question**

Although my question is quite elementary, I would like to ask the following: if $f$ is piecewise constant with respect to $\textbf{P}$ and $\textbf{P}'$, then necessarily $\textbf{P}$ is finer than $\textbf{P}'$ or $\textbf{P}'$ is finer than $\textbf{P}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For instance, consider a constant function and any two partitions.